# Connecting two emulators using IP address

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

We are doing android chat application as project.We need the help for connecting two emulators using IP address in MySQL database.We will be grateful for any help in this regard.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you done so far? do you have an issue (like an exception which you are unable to resolve). this is not a forum for open-ended questions.. we can help you but you need to tell us exactly what your issue is..

Comment: @AnanthaSharmas comment is good. Also where does MySQL come in to the picture? I don't understand...

Comment: @AnanthaSharma sorry for the glare information. Since we are new to android and stack overflow mistake happened.We finished with the design phase. now we need to create a network between two emulators and we thought of connecting the two devices using IP. So we need help in connecting two emulators and can send chat among each other. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant We are planning to store the details related to the users in the sqlite and Mysql will be used to store the information regarding all the users. Cant we implement like this. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

you could forward a port on your local computer to the emulator1 and send requests from emulator2 request through the local computer's port, it'll be forwarded to emulator1.

[this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports) can help very much

Comment: @Ananthashama whether this can be applied using two different emulators running on two different systems. Thank you for your feed back